# Ways to parallelize this using OpenMP?

Tags: openmp

Can anybody suggest a best way to parallelize this using openmp? The program gets aborted when I run this code.

```
void grayerode(int **img, int height, int width, int filterheight,
            int filterwidth, int iterations, int pixrange) 
    {

      int maxlabel=0;
      int fh, fw, iters, pixval=0, i, j, s, k;
      int fhlimit = filterheight/2;
      int fwlimit = filterwidth/2;
      int **smoothedlabels;

      allocate_2D_int_matrix ( &smoothedlabels, height, width );

     #pragma omp parallel for shared(smoothedlabels,height,width,k) 

    for (i=0; i<height; i++)
        for (j=0; j<width; j++)
          smoothedlabels[i][j] = img[i][j];

      int *labeltemp = (int *)malloc(pixrange*sizeof(int));
      for (s=0; s<pixrange; s++)
        labeltemp[s] = 0;

      for (iters=0; iters<iterations; iters++) {
      #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,labeltemp)
        for (i=fhlimit; i<height-fhlimit; i++) {
          for (j=fwlimit; j<width-fwlimit; j++) {

        for (fh=-fhlimit; fh<=fhlimit; fh++)
          for (fw=-fwlimit; fw<=fwlimit; fw++) {
            labeltemp[img[i+fh][j+fw]]++;
          }

        for (s=0; s<pixrange; s++) {
          if (labeltemp[s]>maxlabel) {
            maxlabel = labeltemp[s];
            pixval = s;
          }
        }

        smoothedlabels[i][j]=pixval;

        for (s=0; s<pixrange; s++)
          labeltemp[s] = 0;
        maxlabel = 0;
          }
        }
      }  
        for (i=0; i<height; i++)
          for (j=0; j<width; j++)
        img[i][j] = smoothedlabels[i][j];



      free_2D_int_matrix ( &smoothedlabels );
      free(labeltemp);
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

You are not declaring private variables correctly. One example of doing it the correct way in your code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) shared(smoothedlabels, img, width, height)
for(i=0; i<height; i++)
  for(j=0; j<width; j++)
     smoothedlabels[i][j] = img[i][j]
```

It is important that j remains private or each thread will try change its value - giving you unexpected behaviour. (*Note: i is actually implicitly declared private when you declare the pragma statement, but I always prefer to state it explicitly for better readability*)

Try avoiding 2D arrays because they restrict your ability to parallelize. In the same example you could do the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(width, height, smoothedlabels, img)
for(i=0; i<width * height; i++)
    smoothedlabels[i] = img[i]
```

This will parallelize the entire loop for you rather than just the outer loop. You can order your 1D array either column wise or row wise.

Same thing goes for the rest of the loops - just apply the same concept.

Later in your code for example, you have the following:

```
for (fh=-fhlimit; fh<=fhlimit; fh++)
  for (fw=-fwlimit; fw<=fwlimit; fw++) {
      labeltemp[img[i+fh][j+fw]]++;
  }
```

If you do not declare fh and fw private, then you will get unexpected behaviour for the same reason not declaring j before would give you unexpected behaviour.

Comment: In OpenMP 3 you can use `collapse(2)` for two-dimensional arrays. It preserves the benefits of readability and doesn't restrict parallelization.

Comment: I am aware of collapse but I find it can have undesirable effects in some cases. For example, if you try access i or j when using collapse [your performance wont be optimal](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-collapse-directive). For this reason I prefer to stick to organising my data structures in a manner which promotes better parallelism.